# Redirect any page to Login screen on Session timeout ASP MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So far I have the following but it seems not to be working.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/LogOff";
    options.CookieName = "Yummy";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Authorization:ExpireTimeSpan"), "c", null);
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/";
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow below URL for Autologut

[Use Usertimeout js for Auto redirect to login page](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Session-Timeout-Alert-Plugin-With-jQuery-userTimeout.html)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without any javascript library

Comment: I think it is not possible in back side but i am not sure